# Weird partitions after cloning my disk to SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, disk-cloning

To start, I have three partitions on my disk, don't aske me why, I took this HDD years ago from my older PC then upgraded the O.S. twice, one from XP to W7 then from W7 to W10 and I'm so much grate that I skipped both Vista and W8 will never stop to thanks for that.

[image]

Now I'd like to understand if it is my system that has partitions messed up or if it is the Samsung software to not correcly recognize the other two partitions, also would be really cool to know if I have to carry over those two small partitions forever.

[image]

This is the end result, why the 500 MB partition mapped to E: drive? I can try cloning the disk with Macrium Reflect, it allow me to copy/paste via drag & drop the exact same three partitions, would that be better than using the Samsung Data Migration software? Should I like delete the two small partitions and then just copy using Samsung software?

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of any old partitions this way:

1. Backup your old system partition to an external drive (e.g. using Macrium Refelect)
2. Delete everything on the SSD and perform a fresh Windows 10 install (make sure you are booting in UEFI mode, we only need the GPT partition layout and UEFI/boot/recovery partitions).
3. Now overwrite the newly created system partition with your backup and execute the boot repair wizard of Macrium reflect.

I the end you have a Windows 10 booting in UEFI mode (most likly the old installation was not using UEFI) and only the required partitions for Windows 10.